# Storing resource file(.resx) into the cache and reading it from there instead

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using resource file to read the resources from.I am using LINQ to read the resources i.e. First of all I am loading the resource xml file in the XDocument and then querying the xml through LINQ to get the resource value.The problem is that everytime I need to read the resource value I have to load the resource file again and again i.e. the following line of code gets executed everytime:

```cs
XDocument resourceXML = XDocument.Load("path to resource file");
```

This in turn has an impact on the performance of application.

What I need is that I want the resource XML to be stored in CACHE and every time I need to read the XML to get the resource value I can read it from cache itself instead of time and again loading the .resx file.This I know will definately improve the performance of my application.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the facilities built into .NET for loading resources, rather than loading and parsing them yourself?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using resource file to read the resources from.I am using LINQ to
>   read the resources i.e. First of all I am loading the resource xml
>   file in the XDocument and then querying the xml through LINQ to get
>   the resource value

And you are doing in order to read a value stored in a resource file this instead of simply using the autogenerated strongly typed class: `ResourceName.SomeResourceKey`?

And if your answer is *yes I have my reasons*, then you may take a look at the [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) namespace which contains all you need in order to cache data in a .NET application. For example there's the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class. The `System.Runtime.Caching` assembly has been added in .NET 4.0 so if you are using older versions of the framework you could use the [ASP.NET Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx).

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code that loads the resource file in the cache and from there on we can read it.